# sails-permissions getting all permissions

Tags: sails.js, sails-permissions

I am trying to send all the permissions for an authenticated user via JSON from Sails.

My current code to find permissions for a single model type:

```
hasPermission: function hasPermission(req, res) {
    var permitted = PermissionService.isAllowedToPerformAction({
        method: req.param('method'),
        model: sails.models[req.param('model')],
        user: req.user
    });

    return res.json(200, { permitted: permitted });
}
```

This code doesn't work as `isAllowedToPerformAction` wants a single instance of a model. Is there a way to return a single JSON file accounting for all permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try creating roles and give them permissions.
2. Assign role to users

Ex.

```
PermissionService.createRole({
   name: 'carsCategoryAdmin', 
   permissions: [
      { action: 'update', model: 'review', criteria: [{ where: { category: 'cars'}}]}, 
      { action: 'delete', model: 'review', criteria: [{ where: { category: 'cars'}}]}
   ],
   users: ['venise']
})
```

You can examine the role and related permissions and users,

```
Role.find({name:'carsCategoryAdmin'})
  .populate('users')
  .populate('permissions')
  .exec(console.log)
```

See more @ [sails-permissions-by-example](http://threeninetyfive.net/blog/2015/07/14/sails-permissions-by-example/)

See how to get [user permissions](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/256) with code in comment given by **skrichten on May 10, 2014** .

Comment: Your answer works for getting the data for one Role but it doesn't say much about getting all permissions into a readable form.

Comment: Yes this can be done. @BeaverusIV. Giving you example to get all permissions. And I missed the bounty :(